# How to extract all values from specific key in dictionary?

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to extract all the values from the "externalIps" key from this example dictionary

```
{
    "a": {},
    "b": {},
    "c": {},
    "d": {
        "us-east1-b": {
            "vm1": {
                "externalIps": [
                    "1.1.1.1"
                ],
                "resourceowner": "bob@bob.com"
            }
        }
    },
    "e": {
        "us-east1-b": {
            "vm2": {
                "externalIps": [
                    "2.2.2.2"
                ],
                "resourceowner": "jane@jane.com"
            },
            "vm3": {
                "externalIps": [
                    "3.3.3.3"
                ],
                "resourceowner": "joe@joe.com"
            },
            "vm4": {
                "externalIps": [
                    "4.4.4.4"
                ],
                "resourceowner": "susan@susan.com"
            }
        }
    },
    "f": {},
    "g": {
        "us-east1-b": {
            "vm5": {
                "externalIps": [
                    "5.5.5.5"
                ],
                "resourceowner": "tim@tim.com"
            }
        }
    },
}
```

I'm using python 3.7.3 on linux.  I have tried many things such as "for key, value in" , and other things I've search for on the web.  Given the different keys everywhere, I'm not sure how to just reference the "externalIps" key and get its values.

Closest I've gotten is something like this, which just seems super-inefficient and fails when I try to go to key5

```
for key1 in json_data.keys():
    for key2 in json_data[key1].keys():
        for key3 in json_data[key1][key2].keys():
            for key4 in json_data[key1][key2][key3].keys():
                print(key4)
```

I want the result to be something like this:

1.1.1.1,2.2.2.2,3.3.3.3,4.4.4.4,5.5.5.5

Comment: can you add what you tried to the question

Comment: I've added my inefficent code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use recursion to accomplish what you need:

```
d = {
    "a": {},
    "b": {},
    "c": {},
    "d": {
        "us-east1-b": {
            "vm1": {
                "externalIps": [
                    "1.1.1.1"
                ],
                "resourceowner": "bob@bob.com"
            }
        }
    },
    "e": {
        "us-east1-b": {
            "vm2": {
                "externalIps": [
                    "2.2.2.2"
                ],
                "resourceowner": "jane@jane.com"
            },
            "vm3": {
                "externalIps": [
                    "3.3.3.3"
                ],
                "resourceowner": "joe@joe.com"
            },
            "vm4": {
                "externalIps": [
                    "4.4.4.4"
                ],
                "resourceowner": "susan@susan.com"
            }
        }
    },
    "f": {},
    "g": {
        "us-east1-b": {
            "vm5": {
                "externalIps": [
                    "5.5.5.5"
                ],
                "resourceowner": "tim@tim.com"
            }
        }
    },
}

def fn(d, rv):
    for k, v in d.items():
        if k == 'externalIps':
            rv.append(v[0])
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            fn(v, rv)

l = []
fn(d, rv=l)
print(l)
```

Prints:

```
['1.1.1.1', '2.2.2.2', '3.3.3.3', '4.4.4.4', '5.5.5.5']
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple way would be to just use regex:

```py
import re
data = {
    "a": {},
    "b": {},
    "c": {},
    "d": {
        "us-east1-b": {
            "vm1": {
                "externalIps": [
                    "1.1.1.1"
                ],
                "resourceowner": "bob@bob.com"
            }
        }
    },
    "e": {
        "us-east1-b": {
            "vm2": {
                "externalIps": [
                    "2.2.2.2"
                ],
                "resourceowner": "jane@jane.com"
            },
            "vm3": {
                "externalIps": [
                    "3.3.3.3"
                ],
                "resourceowner": "joe@joe.com"
            },
            "vm4": {
                "externalIps": [
                    "4.4.4.4"
                ],
                "resourceowner": "susan@susan.com"
            }
        }
    },
    "f": {},
    "g": {
        "us-east1-b": {
            "vm5": {
                "externalIps": [
                    "5.5.5.5"
                ],
                "resourceowner": "tim@tim.com"
            }
        }
    },
}
results = re.findall(r"'externalIps'.*?'(.*?)'", str(data))
#print results
for result in results:
   print (result)
```

This is a basic method though and probably not efficient.

Comment: Thanks.. If noone else comes up with anything I'll take an inefficient one that works!